# Is there any keyword in vba to clear the default values in a website to replace with a new one?

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping, automation, internet-explorer-11

While filling in different forms, username, inputbox or similar things in different websites, I sometimes noticed that the very options [`forms, username, inputbox`] are already filled in with default values. So, at this point I need to clear the existing values to replace with new ones. I searched a lot to find the keyword but could not. I tried with `.clear` but it didn't work and my script breaks here throwing an error "object doesn't support this----".

My question is whether there is any option in vba to clear the default content so that I can fill in with my desired one?

What I tried so far:

```
Set itm_date = html.getElementById("sDate")
itm_date.Focus
itm_date.Clear 'this is what I'm taking about
Application.SendKeys "10/01/2017"
```

To bring the clarity, I'm attaching an image which is already filled in with a default date. I wish to kick it out with any command in vba.

[image: click_to_see]

Comment: Have you tried `Unload.Me`? Or `Textbox1.Value = "Some Value"` before you load the userform?

Comment: It seems my question has misled you @K.Davis. Trying to edit my post to make it clearer.

Comment: well the default is set in the html, do you have access to the html?  Because It is a website you are using VBA to "fill in" the editable fields I take it.  You can't change the defaults they are run at the time the html is interpreted by the browser and provided in line in html. It is often controlled by the value property such as in this text input example: <input type="text" value="default value">

Comment: What about `ieObj.Document.Forms(0).Reset`?

Comment: In my experience you can replace what is in the field but to do what you want you would have to overwrite the code at run time which is how bad people do bad things.  You need access to the code and the server . . .

Comment: Yes that is editable. I can manually edit that value. I can automatically replace that value with my script using `.value` property or `.innerText` property. However, I haven't erected my question to bypass the error or to have any workaround to input any date in that box. My question is very clear: Is there any command/keyword in vba to clear the content in such fields?

Comment: @novice-coder Wouldn't `itm_date.value = ""` do what you need to do? Or am I misunderstanding the question?

Comment: You are the gem @user3561813. You hit the bull's eye. Please, post it as an answer so that i can accept it. Thanks again.

Comment: `itm_date.value` is the programmers way of reading/writing a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `.Clear` method to clear the value in the HTML input.

Instead, use `itm_date.value = ""` to clear the control.

Comment: I could not upvote your solution only because I don't have enough reputation but I'll for sure when I have. Thanks again.